# "Я знаю, что делать." - разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

```
Я знаю, что делать.
```

Какими членом предложения является **делать**?

Answer (score 1):

***Я знаю, что делать.***

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным,  придаточное – односоставное инфинитивное предложение. Главный член выражен независимым инфинитивом. Что – союзное слово в роли дополнения.

Инфинитив широко используется в вопросительных предложениях: Что делать? С чего начать?
[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)  стр. 92

Comment: неверно, придаточное тут не инфинитивное;)

Comment: Что делать? Это инфинитивное предложение? У Кустовой инфинитивное.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в примерах Кустовой нигде нельзя вставить связки типа "нужно". Которые очевидным образом превращают предложение в стандартное безличное предложение. "Что нужно делать?" безличное предложение. Кустова старательно обходит этот момент. Тыкнете пальцем где она называет это инфинитивным?

Comment: Я же вам страничку указала.  В издании  2013 года она приводит три примера инфинитивных предложений: Что делать? С чего начать?  Как пройти в библиотеку?  Связок у них нет,   парадигма состоит из одного предложения. Что нужно делать - безличное предложение,

Comment: Ссылка у вас на издание 2005 года.

Comment: Другой нет, она новые издания онлайн не выкладывает.

Comment: В общем да, узрел в издании 2013 года. Скажу, что это явная демагогия, два одинаковых предложения "Что нужно делать" и "Что делать" классифицировать по-разному. Замечу, что в куче других учебников этот вопрос тоже обходят стороной, говоря о неоднозначности инфинитивных предложений как таковых.

Comment: Не вижу демагогии. Инфинитивы - это особая краткая экспрессивная речь, где важно выразить только само действие, модальность там ни к чему. В этих предложениях свои правила.

Comment: Вот именно, модальность в них ни к чему, это особая "рубленная" речь. А тут плавная речь, в которую вполне напрашивается модальность. Это безличное предложение.

Comment: Чем выражено сказуемое в вашем безличном предложении?

Comment: Я знаю, что делать = Я знаю, что было(есть) делать. Сказуемое одно и то же в этих двух предложениях= было(есть) делать.

Comment: Пропущенный модальный предикатив?  Уникальный случай! Кто-нибудь еще разделяет ваше мнение?

Comment: Ничего уникального. Связка "есть" постоянно пропускается. Разделяют многие, поэтому и сомнения у Кустовой в 2005 году.

Comment: Я знаю, что было нужно делать. Это вариант со связкой. Случай с вашим предложением, конечно, интересный, но убедительного решения я пока не вижу.